# ViewModel as source type for new object with Automapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

Is it possible to use an ViewModel object (ViewModels.Combined) that holds two Lists (domains and reginfos) as a source type for Automapper?

Sample source code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var domains = from x in unitofwork.DomainRepository.Get()
                          select x;

            var reginfos = from x in unitofwork.RegInfoRepository.Get()
                           select x;

            var combined = new Combined(domains, reginfos);

            Mapper.CreateMap<Combined, Home>();
            Home[] something = Mapper.Map<Combined[], Home[]>(combined); // throws error

            return View();
        }
```

The ideal situation would be to flatten ViewModels.Combined and be able to use ex. Model.domains.FullName.

Thanks in advance and sorry for mixing up term. I'm pretty new to mvc and .net

Comment: The variable combined looks like an object and I would have thought that you would have a compilation error rather than a thrown exception. What error are you getting?

Comment: As @GruffBunny mentioned you would get a compile error. I guess your source be the "Combined" and the destination would be "Home". The below code would produce the desired behaviour?                         Home something = Mapper.Map<Combined, Home>(combined);

Comment: Combined is and object that holds two Lists that are coming from two models(repositories). I would like to flatten? Combined model into Home and be able to use that Home model (as List) in a View. I have an error saying error line has some invalid arguments which is not much help for me...